# Understanding the source of a 'Failed to get available update data' errors

Tags: updating

When manually checking module updates for a customer site all modules update OK (and are updating fine) but there is an error saying "Failed to get available update data for 2 projects."

I suspect this is due to a custom theme and/or module that cannot update but with quite a few modules on this site. How can I identify what these "2 projects" are? I can't see anything on the admin site. I tried drush with pm-update with verbose and debug but can't see anything.

I'm assuming once identified that the next step would be to lock those modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, I would suggest the following on a terminal:

```
drush pm-updatestatus 2>&1 | grep "No release history" -B1
```

This should give you all the projects (modules and themes) that you are looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: After upgrading my drush from the apt installed 5.10 (pm-updatestatus command didn't exist) to the latest 8.1.2 this command does reveal the two modules that aren't updateable. Thanks!